# Jquery search more than one variable - bigcommerce store checkout

Tags: javascript, jquery, bigcommerce

I am having an issue with this code when I try to search for more than one variable.

the main purpose of this code is the hide the credit card checkout buttons and only leave the PayPal button.

```
<script>
setInterval(function() {
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
setTimeout( function(){ 
jQuery(".button--tertiary").attr("onclick", "abc1()");
jQuery("#checkout-customer-continue").attr("onclick", "abc1()");
}  , 500 );
 setTimeout( function(){    
 var searchValue = "46468";
$(".product").each(function(){
if($(this).html().indexOf(searchValue) > -1){
$('label[for="radio-authorizenet"], label[for="radio-bankdeposit"], .paymentMethod--creditCard').hide();
}
});
}  , 500 ); 
    });
}, 250);
</script>
```

the var the code is searching is "46468" but I want to search more than one var for example "46468, 46467, 46469". I try using an array like this

```
 var searchValue = [ "46468", "46467", "46469"]
```

but it is not working, any other options?

Comment: Are you able to construct a regular expression to search against? Or will it always just be an array of values?

Comment: it will be an array of values

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like:

```
if($(this).html().indexOf(searchValueOne) > -1 || $(this).html().indexOf(searchValueTwo) > -1 || $(this).html().indexOf(searchValueThree) > -1){
     $('label[for="radio-authorizenet"], label[for="radio-bankdeposit"], .paymentMethod--creditCard').hide();
}
```

This would work unless it were something like 100 numbers. Otherwise you could look through the array. Which would look something like:

```
foreach(arrayOfNumbers as number){
    $(".product").each(function(){
         if($(this).html().indexOf(number) > -1){
            $('label[for="radio-authorizenet"], label[for="radio-bankdeposit"], .paymentMethod--creditCard').hide();
         } 
    })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you wanted to search for multiple distinct values then you could write a loop to run through all the values and repeat the search for each value.

```
var searchValues = ["46468", "46467", "46469"];
$(".product").each(function() {
  for (i = 0; i < searchValues.length; i++) {
    if ($(this).html().indexOf(searchValues[i]) > -1) {
      $('label[for="radio-authorizenet"], label[for="radio-bankdeposit"], .paymentMethod--creditCard').hide();
    }
  }
});
```

It's simplistic and maybe not the most efficient, but as a basic alteration to your existing code it should work.